# Getting error when run KMM project for IOS app after add io ktor dependency

Tags: ios, kotlin, apple-m1, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to build KMM project following kotlinlang.org/docs on my Mac M1

Getting error when run KMM project for IOS app after add `io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.2.2` dependency

It is working fine without `io.ktor` dependencies, but its failed with io ktor `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

My Gradle verions: 7.5

How I can solve this issue?

[image: gradle.kts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issues a few days back. Here's how I solved it:

**Step 1**

upgrade: `ktorVersion = "2.2.2"`

to: `ktorVersion = "2.2.3"`

**Step 2**

In your `build.gradle.kts`

upgrade: `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")`

to: `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20")`

**Step 3**

In your `build.gradle.kts` `(:shared)` remove the below code if you've previously used it

[image]